# PHP not returning data on Ajax Call?

Tags: javascript, php, json, heroku

I have this unusual problem in heroku, where I'm loading some session data from a PHP backend using Javascript fetch.

The php file looks like this,

```
<?php
  session_start();
  header('Content-Type: application/json');

  $data = json_encode($_SESSION['data']);
  print_r($data);
```

And calls it using a Javascript

```
fetch('./data.php')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json()
  }).then(function(json) {
    console.log('parsed json', json)
  }).catch(function(ex) {
    console.log('parsing failed', ex)
  })
```

When I load the data from my browser the output on the console is, **parsed json null**

But when I load the same data.php on my browser by directly going to it, it prints data data fine on the browser.

What have I done wrong to make it behave in two different ways when calling using ajax not to work and make it work when directly going to the file? 
Thanks

Comment: Turn on PHP error reporting and check the Network tab in your favorite browser's developer tools.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I did nothing wrong with it, I don't know what's wrong :/

Answer (score 0):

I have executed your code and got null answer because currently, i don't have any data in session data variable.
So, i guess your session data is not working correctly, try to print the session data first separately in your application then, try to execute this code.

Comment: Well when I open the data.php directly from the browser the session data is correctly loaded and it does print the data, so I was thinking it has to do something with heroku

Comment: But if it is something related to heroku then it should not return any data. But surprisingly, it is returning testing data as given:session_start();
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  $data = 'jgadhgash';
  $data = json_encode($data);
  print_r($data); I've just tried to output some data.

Comment: I think I've figured it out, it's something to do with the javascript Fetch, when I make the Ajax call using jquery $.get it works. So something wrong with the Fetch API